# Add Forked projects to the same GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I'd like to be able to select the destination folder when I fork a project.

I have to fork different projects from different github accounts (to later do some small changes and do a pull request).
Every time I fork a project, it creates a new repository in my Github.
To keep them more organised , I would like to be able to select the destination of the projects I fork.

The idea would be to create a repo (e.g. *forked_projects* ) , and select that repo as destination every time I fork one.

Is this something possible? and if so, is there any not so complicated way of doing it?

I read about submodules, so I created a repository, with a `.gitsmodules` file and
`[submodule "repository1"] path = repository1 url = https://github.com/username/repository1`
But i really do not know if that is a viable way of doing it, and how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in GitHub website, you don't have this notion of folders.

But you have a filter dropdown that let you see only "forked" repositories:

[image: GitHub repos filtered on Forks]

Using submodule is not easy so I really think it's a bad idea to use that to organize repositories (and it won't remove the clutter on repo list).

Comment: Oh! I that didn't even occurred to me! Thanks a lot for that!